# date validation in javascript using .js files

Tags: javascript, validation, date, calendar

I am having a ini.jsp page for creating a form for adding two text fields to input date and then using javascript in the ini.jsp page itself to validate those dates. I now have some library files(calendar.js, calendar-en.js, calendar-setup.js, calendar_1.png, calendar_system.css).
Now my question is how to I link these files to javascript (I am using ECLIPSE IDE) so that it displays calendar beside the textboxes for date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. . .

I have gone through lots of stuff, tried doing those but really couldn't get the expected output.
Below is the code that i have implemented so far

```
     <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <style type="text/css" src="../datePickers/calendar-system.css">
        </style>
         </head>
        <body>
  <script language="Javascript" src="../Scripts/calendar.js"></script>

<h1>Report Generation</h1>

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; text-align: left">

    <form name="date" action="<c:url value="cli.htm"/>"
        method="post" onSubmit="return ValidateForm()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Please enter Start Date and End Date</legend>

                <div style="text-align: center; margin: 150px auto 100px auto;">
    <label for="dateFrom">Start Date:</label> 
            <font color="#CC0000"><b>(dd/mm /yyyy)</b></font>
            <input type="text" name="dateFrom" maxlength="25" size="25"
                    id="dateFrom" /> 
    <img src = "../Images/calendar_1.png"   onclick="javascript:Calendar.setup(inputField,ifFormat,button) style="cursor: pointer" /> 
            </div>


    <div style="text-align: center; margin: 150px auto 100px auto;">
    <label for="dateTo">End Date:</label> 
            <font color="#CC0000"><b>(dd/mm/yyyy)</b></font>
    <input type="text" name="dateTo" maxlength="25" size="25"
                    id="dateTo" />
            </div>

            <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" align="center" />
            </div>
    </form>
        </div>


           <script language="Javascript" >
            var dtCh= "/";
         var minYear=1900;
         var maxYear=2500;

         function isInteger(s){
     var i;
          for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
     // Checking that the current character is number.
          var c = s.charAt(i);
         if (((c < "0") || (c > "9")))
        return false;
             }
 // All characters are numbers.
              return true;
                }

                function stripCharsInBag(s, bag){
          var i;
                  var returnString = "";
 // Search through string's characters one by one.
 // If character is not in bag, append to returnString.
                  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
             var c = s.charAt(i);
            if (bag.indexOf(c) == -1) returnString += c;
            }
            return returnString;
                         }

                  function daysInFebruary (year){

                    return (((year % 4 == 0) && ( (!(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400  == 0))) ? 29 : 28 );
                    }

                   function DaysArray(n) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           this[i] = 31
            if (i==4 || i==6 || i==9 || i==11) {this[i] = 30}
           if (i==2) {this[i] = 29}
                     }  
                    return this
                        }


                 function isDate(dtStr){

               var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12)
                var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh)
                var pos2=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1)
                 var strDay=dtStr.substring(0,pos1)
                 var strMonth=dtStr.substring(pos1+1,pos2)
                  var strYear=dtStr.substring(pos2+1)
                               strYr = strYear
                if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1) strDay=strDay.substring(1)
if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1) strMonth=strMonth.substring(1)
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1)
}
month=parseInt(strMonth)
day=parseInt(strDay)
year=parseInt(strYr)
if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
    alert("The date format should be : dd/mm/yyyy");
    return false;
}
if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
    alert("Please enter a valid month");
    return false;
}
if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
    alert("Please enter a valid day");
    return false;
}
if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear || year>maxYear){
    alert("Please enter a valid 4 digit year between "+minYear+" and "+maxYear);
    return false;
}
if (dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(dtStr, dtCh))== false){
    alert("Please enter a valid date");
    return false;
}
       return true;
            }


              function ValidateForm(){
           var dt1=document.date.dateFrom
       var dt2=document.date.dateTo

        if (!isDate(dt1.value)){
    dt1.value='';
    dt1.focus();
    return false;
}
if(!isDate(dt2.value)){
    dt2.value='';
    dt2.focus();
    return false;
}


     return true
     }


    }
     </script>
  </body>
   </html>
```

I want changes in code to be done as:

The code should initialises the calendar object and links an image  to a text field (using their IDs) to respond to a click.

Calendar.setup(
     {
       inputField  : "dateFrom",    // ID of the input field
       ifFormat    : "%d/%m/%Y",   // the date format
       button      : "imgCal"     // ID of the calendar image
     }
);

should I really need to create a calendar object if so, can I know where. Also, where should I place the Calendar.setup code in my jsp page?

Can someone please help me sort out this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Quick suggestion: Have you tried looking into this page.

Easy to implement and you can see the demo as well.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

**

Now, Looking into your code; can you please flick the calender.setup(foo1, foo2...) function implementation? (Is this your customized library?)

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable comments. I have gone through ur link but couldn;t get an idea exactly what I should do..Can you plz find out if there are any errors in the code or any changes...calendar.setup.js file is the library file.should we need to create a object for that? I assume only params should be mentioned..Can u give a further more explaination as how I could do this?

Comment: Hiya, Glad I can help, we will get there: So if I can understand this correctly you want calendar to appear next to this textbox right? you can have a css for your calendar or image as hidden html tag next to that textbox and when the check for valid date [isDate in this case] is invoked you can show the calendar based on that check. ** .show or .hide based on your date validation ?; Hope this helps.

Comment: Can u give an example or code to show how this works...Thanks!

Comment: Sup, No worries man; here you go - So add this element next to your text box. This will be your calendar image which you want to show and hide when the date is valid.
[Code:]
<img id="imgidforyou" src="your/image/path/here" style="visibility: hidden;" />

Now in your isDate function when you check that date is valid add this line
[Code:]
$("#imgidforyou").show()

If its not valid date then;
[Code:]
$("#imgidforyou").hide()

Hope this will help: On the separate topic but I will highly recommend using datepicker as mentioned here
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

Comment: Thanks alot for being so patient. .! But Unfortunately I am hardly finding the code to be failed..the demos were really good..but i am not using jquery to follow these procedures.I believe it makes lots of mess..!! Could I have much more detailed view/changes for my code

Comment: No probs man, did you tried the code I mentioned in my second comment i.e. adding the element next to text box and then showing and hiding it based on your isDate function?, If you dont mind flick me your email address and I will mail you to see what exactly you need. It will also be good to paste exact snippets of code you need for this. cheers,

Comment: Cooleos, emailed you with some details. talk to you in detail there. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to **validate date with **YYYY\MM\DD** of format using HTML and Javascript
Hope its Help you...
try to yourself...

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function valdate() {
    var regdate = /^(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
    if (form1.txtdate.value.match(regdate)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("! please Enter the Date in this Format 'YYYY/MM/DD'");
      form1.txtdate.value = "";
      form1.txtdate.focus();
      return false;
    }
  } < /script>
```

```html
<from="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input name="txtdate" type="text" onblur="valdate()" maxlength="10" required />
  </form>
```

if helpful so *make voting....*